# it is possible to style HIGHCHARTS like this?

Tags: highcharts, styling

it is possible to style HIGHCHARTS like this?
[please see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEieN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. All you need to do is to use zones with x axis.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        ...,
        zoneAxis: 'x',
        zones: [{
            value: 2,
            fillColor: 'red',
            color: 'red'
        }, ...],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pr49c3je/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.zones

Comment: friend thank you very much, I looked at this is not exactly what I need. I want to paint only the area of the graph that is below zero. this solution paints like a mirror. I convinced the customer that since he wants not to receive and did as you suggested. thank you for your help

Comment: Hi @Maria Bergson, Sorry for the misunderstanding, but the solution will be even simpler :) It is enough to change zone-axis. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sqL1k0m5/